# OpenVPN on Azure VM, disconnected every 3 minutes

Tags: azure, openvpn

I followed steps in this article (http://azure-openvpn.github.io/) to establish an OpenVPN Server Access on my azure Ubuntu virtual machine.

Then I referred this page (https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/quick-start-guide/495-connecting-to-openvpn-access-server-using-the-connect-client-on-mac.html) to connect from my Mac.

It connected successfully but I found it disconnected after 3 minutes, re-connected and then disconnected after 3 minutes.

Looks like something in front of my virtual machine closed VPN the connection by timeout, since it happened every 3 minutes. I checked documents in azure and google-ed, but didn't find anything related.

Any ideas? BTW, my virtual machine was in Japan West.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really sounds like the load balancer is closing the connection due to inactivity.

You can change the default idle timeout and increase it up to 30 minutes. You can find more information at [New configurable idle timeout for the Azure Load Balancer](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/14/new-configurable-idle-timeout-for-azure-load-balancer/)

Comment: Set load balancer idle timeout for TCP endpoint (UDP doesn't support this feature) and force my OpenVPN Connect to use TCP, it kept connected over 10 minutes.